# for loop runs only once in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

In Js file:

```
$scope.isCheckboxChecked = function() {
        var chks = document.getElementsByName('chk[]');
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
        {
            if (chks[i].checked) 
            {
                $scope.checkBoxClicked = true;
                $('#btnUpdateData').attr("data-target", "#update-modal");
                $('#btnUpdateData').attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                break;
            }
            if ($scope.checkBoxClicked == false)
            {
                alert("Please select at least one checkbox");
            }            
        }
    }
```

In HTML

```
  <div class="row" style="">
        <button type="button" id="btnUpdateData" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="isCheckboxChecked()">Update</button>
    </div>
```

This code checks if the checkbox is checked only once.
once the checkbox is unchecked, I want the for loop to run again.

Comment: missing HTML some code?

Comment: try without the break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Plunkr example of how you could watch a checkbox's statechange and do something when it changes:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kyEv7IyAXGFRdZjaD4vM?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.$watch("testCheckBox", function(newVal, oldVal){
       alert('Checkbox changed!')
   });

});
```

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <p>Check box test</p>
 <input type="checkbox" name="testCheckbox" ng-model="testCheckBox"></input>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: But the checkboxes are created inside an ng-repeat.

Comment: Hence I cannot give different names.

Comment: You could create a form and give each checkbox a form name plus add the $index of the repeat to make each name unique. Then just watch changes to the whole form instead of each control.

Comment: Thank you very much . Got it fixed.